# Rails: cannot load fixtures for table using STI (undefined method `reflect_on_all_associations')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, fixtures, single-table-inheritance, database-migration

I can't load fixtures for my table that uses STI.

When I call `FIXTURES=schools rake db:fixtures:load`, I get this error:

```
undefined method `reflect_on_all_associations' for Object:Class
```

- Other fixtures load fine, i.e. `FIXTURES=committes rake db:fixtures:load`
- The fixture was created by calling `rake db:fixtures:extract`

Here's my schools migration:

```
class CreateSchools < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :schools do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :type
      t.string :street
      t.string :city
      t.string :province
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
...
end
```

I have a few model files, i.e. `school.rb`:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

And `secondary_school.rb`:

```
class SecondarySchool < School
end
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
undefined method `reflect_on_all_associations' for Object:Class
/home/loranaw/ruby/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.10/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:597:in `insert_fixtures'
/home/loranaw/ruby/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.10/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:568:in `each'
/home/loranaw/ruby/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.10/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:568:in `insert_fixtures'
/home/loranaw/ruby/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.10/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:512:in `create_fixtures'
/home/loranaw/ruby/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.10/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:512:in `each'
/home/loranaw/ruby/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.10/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:512:in `create_fixtures'
/home/loranaw/ruby/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in `transaction'
/home/loranaw/ruby/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.10/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:510:in `create_fixtures'
/home/loranaw/ruby/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:267:in `disable_referential_integrity'
/home/loranaw/ruby/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.10/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:501:in `create_fixtures'
/home/loranaw/ruby/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.10/lib/active_record/base.rb:1482:in `silence'
/home/loranaw/ruby/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.10/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:500:in `create_fixtures'
/home/loranaw/ruby/gems/gems/rails-2.3.10/lib/tasks/databases.rake:223
/home/loranaw/ruby/gems/gems/rails-2.3.10/lib/tasks/databases.rake:222:in `each'
/home/loranaw/ruby/gems/gems/rails-2.3.10/lib/tasks/databases.rake:222
```

And some sample YML:

```
--- 
schools_7133: 
  city: Nahanni Butte
  name: Charles Yohin School
  created_at: 2010-11-26 02:36:39
  grade_range: K-10
  latitude: "61.03349"
  country: CA
  updated_at: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
  postal_code: "X0E 0N0"
  url: 
  street: ""
  id: "9682"
  type: SecondarySchool
  fax: (867) 602-2202
  phone: (867) 602-2200
  funding: 
  longitude: "-123.38642"
  school_type: 
  province: NT
  email:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being one of records had a blank/empty value for type. Make sure *every* row in your STI table has a type.

Answer (score 0):

The School object has a field called type, which is reserved for Single Table Inheritance. renaming that field should solve the problem .

Comment: I am using STI. Type is being used to store SecondarySchool, PrimarySchool, etc.

Comment: Are you still getting the error even after renaming type to say school_type? The "type" keyword is protected and has been really discriminating programmers even while doing direct updates using the update_attribute method. So I suggest you to rename it rather than actually trying to bypass it somehow.

Comment: If you did not understand me then what I am actually trying to say is in you rails migration where you are creating the schools you should rename the  t.string :type to  t.string :school_type. Hope this should make things clear

Comment: I need to set the schools' type upon creation.

Comment: @Raghu if you haven't heard or read about Single Table Inheritance(STI) then you can refer this http://rohitsharma9889.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/implement-sti-single-table-inheritance-in-your-rails-models/

Comment: @rohit you should probably restrict your comments to the question that been actually asked . @paul check this http://apptrain.blogspot.com/2009/12/undefined-method-reflectonallassociatio.html

Comment: @Raghu I just wanted to say that @paul is trying to check if the STI implemented by him is working or not. And I think this might not be accomplished by changing the :type field name to something else. No hard feelings though

Comment: @rohit Oh ok :) That should be fine dude :)